# How I am struggling to have my fixed sidebar menu on desktop/laptop to switch into hamburger menu on mobile / tablets

Tags: html, css

I am really struggling to get this to work even though I am clear on my mind on what i want to achieve. What I want to achieve is a responsive layout for my website where the sidebar menu is fixed on desktop and laptop, but then is switched to hamburger menu for mobile and tablet ?

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<style>
body {
  font-family: "Lato", sans-serif;
}

.sidebar {
  height: 100%;
  width: 0;
  position: fixed;
  z-index: 1;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  background-color: #111;
  overflow-x: hidden;
  transition: 0.5s;
  padding-top: 60px;
}

.sidebar a {
  padding: 9px 8px 8px 32px;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-size: 25px;
  color: #818181;
  display: block;
  transition: 0.3s;
}

.sidebar a:hover {
  color: #f1f1f1;
}

.sidebar .closebtn {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  right: 25px;
  font-size: 36px;
  margin-left: 50px;
}

.openbtn {
  font-size: 20px;
  cursor: pointer;
  background-color: #111;
  color: white;
  padding: 10px 15px;
  border: none;
}

.openbtn:hover {
  background-color: #444;
}

#main {
  transition: margin-left .5s;
  padding: 16px;
}

/* On smaller screens, where height is less than 450px, change the style of the sidenav (less padding and a smaller font size) */
@media screen and (max-height: 450px) {
  .sidebar {padding-top: 15px;}
  .sidebar a {font-size: 18px;}
}
</style>
</head>
<body>

<div id="mySidebar" class="sidebar">
  <a href="javascript:void(0)" class="closebtn" onclick="closeNav()">×</a>
  <a href="#">About</a>
  <a href="#">Services</a>
  <a href="#">Clients</a>
  <a href="#">Contact</a>
</div>

<div id="main">
  <button class="openbtn" onclick="openNav()">☰ Open Sidebar</button>  
  <h2>Collapsed Sidebar</h2>
  <p>Click on the hamburger menu/bar icon to open the sidebar, and push this content to the right.</p>
</div>

<script>
function openNav() {
  document.getElementById("mySidebar").style.width = "250px";
  document.getElementById("main").style.marginLeft = "250px";
}

function closeNav() {
  document.getElementById("mySidebar").style.width = "0";
  document.getElementById("main").style.marginLeft= "0";
}
</script>
   
</body>
</html>
```

Many thanks for the help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You just need to set the values you are changing (`width`, `margin-left`, etc.) when toggling the menu via JS to be present and then change them to what you originally had using that `media query`. Additionally, you might want to hide and show the toggle buttons.

Here's an approach:

```css
body {
  font-family: "Lato", sans-serif;
}

.sidebar {
  height: 100%;
  width: 250px;
  position: fixed;
  z-index: 1;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  background-color: #111;
  overflow-x: hidden;
  transition: 0.5s;
  padding-top: 60px;
}

.sidebar a {
  padding: 9px 8px 8px 32px;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-size: 25px;
  color: #818181;
  display: block;
  transition: 0.3s;
}

.sidebar a:hover {
  color: #f1f1f1;
}

.sidebar .closebtn {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  right: 25px;
  font-size: 36px;
  margin-left: 50px;
  display: none;
}

.openbtn {
  font-size: 20px;
  cursor: pointer;
  background-color: #111;
  color: white;
  padding: 10px 15px;
  border: none;
  display: none;
}

.openbtn:hover {
  background-color: #444;
}

#main {
  transition: margin-left .5s;
  padding: 16px;
  margin-left: 250px;
}


/* On smaller screens, where height is less than 450px, change the style of the sidenav (less padding and a smaller font size) */

@media screen and (max-height: 450px) {
  .sidebar {
    padding-top: 15px;
    width: 0;
  }
  .sidebar a {
    font-size: 18px;
  }
  .openbtn {
    display: block;
  }
  .sidebar .closebtn {
    display: block;
  }
  #main {
    margin-left: 0;
  }
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
</head>

<body>

  <div id="mySidebar" class="sidebar">
    <a href="javascript:void(0)" class="closebtn" onclick="closeNav()">×</a>
    <a href="#">About</a>
    <a href="#">Services</a>
    <a href="#">Clients</a>
    <a href="#">Contact</a>
  </div>

  <div id="main">
    <button class="openbtn" onclick="openNav()">☰ Open Sidebar</button>
    <h2>Collapsed Sidebar</h2>
    <p>Click on the hamburger menu/bar icon to open the sidebar, and push this content to the right.</p>
  </div>
  <script>
    function openNav() {
      document.getElementById("mySidebar").style.width = "250px";
      document.getElementById("main").style.marginLeft = "250px";
    }

    function closeNav() {
      document.getElementById("mySidebar").style.width = "0";
      document.getElementById("main").style.marginLeft = "0";
    }
  </script>
</body>

</html>
```

**Fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/1czk379m/2/**

**EDIT**:
Looks like there was some conflict between styles when resizing the window after toggling the menu. Changed the action of `closeNav()` to remove the elements' inline style. Also changed `.sidebar` to `#mySidebar` on css.

**Take a look at the [updated fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/myj6cz0k/)**

Comment: Hi ajmnz, I have just seen something strange, If I set the viewport screen to mobile size and then click on the hamburger icon to open and then close it again, if I then increase the viewport size to a desktop then the sidebar no longer shows up??

Comment: Looks like inline css set via js has more priority. Updated my answer.

Comment: Yes ! It works fine now, I just checked. Thank you so very much